# query for calculating the total of a field using php

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using PHP. I want to write a query satisfying some conditions.

```
Add totals from field_id=198 for logged-in [userid] if
wp_frm_item_metas field_id=253 where meta_value=Complete
and
wp_frm_item_metas field_id=278 wheremeta_value=Yes
and
wp_frm_item_metas field_id=212 is between Begin and End date
wp_frm_item_metas field_id=270wheremeta_value=[userid of logged in user]
```

table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_frm_item_metas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext,
  `field_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=200 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

table data

```
INSERT INTO `wp_frm_item_metas` (`id`, `meta_value`, `field_id`, `item_id`, `created_at`) VALUES
(2072, '591.00', 198, 181, '2015-05-17 22:10:02'),
(1640, 'Complete', 253, 156, '2015-05-14 21:38:26'),
(1714, 'Complete', 253, 161, '2015-05-16 02:11:50'),
(1747, 'Complete', 253, 163, '2015-05-16 02:23:13'),
(1909, 'Complete', 253, 172, '2015-05-17 01:12:11'),
(2094, 'Yes', 278, 182, '2015-05-17 23:31:03'),
(2113, 'Yes', 278, 183, '2015-05-17 23:42:11'),
(2090, '2015-05-19', 212, 182, '2015-05-17 23:31:03'),
(2109, '2015-05-20', 212, 183, '2015-05-17 23:42:11'),
(2100, '106', 270, 182, '2015-05-17 23:31:03'),
(2119, '106', 270, 183, '2015-05-17 23:42:11');

SELECT sum(meta_value) 
  FROM wp_frm_item_metas 
  WHERE field_id=198 
    and meta_value=
     (select meta_value 
       from wp_frm_item_metas 
       where field_id=253 
         and meta_value="Complete") 
    and meta_value=
      (select meta_value 
        from wp_frm_item_metas 
        where field_id=278  
          and meta_value="Yes") 
    and meta_value=
      (select meta_value 
        from wp_frm_item_metas 
        where field_id=270 
          and meta_value=106).
```

I tried this query, but it shows error as:

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

How to find the total sum in 'meta_value' field satisfying the above conditions?

Comment: Have you tried to build the query on your own?

Comment: yes.but it shows error .query:-SELECT sum(`meta_value`) FROM `wp_frm_item_metas` WHERE field_id=198 and meta_value=(select meta_value from `wp_frm_item_metas` where field_id=253 and meta_value="Complete") and meta_value=(select meta_value from `wp_frm_item_metas` where field_id=278 and meta_value="Yes") and meta_value=(select meta_value from `wp_frm_item_metas` where field_id=270 and meta_value=106)

Comment: Can you provide the a table example of the data?

Comment: Try this : SELECT sum(meta_value) FROM wp_frm_item_metas WHERE field_id=198 and meta_value=(select meta_value from wp_frm_item_metas where field_id=253 and meta_value="Complete") and meta_value IN (select meta_value from wp_frm_item_metas where field_id=278 and meta_value="Yes") and meta_value=(select meta_value from wp_frm_item_metas where field_id=270 and meta_value=106)

Comment: What error? Add the query to the question.

Comment: ugh. why so much code in the comments? put them in the question or an answer.

Comment: Your query is fundamentally broken - even if there were no syntax errors, a field cant be equal to three different things.  Also, why are you even using a subquery when all you're doing is returning a value you already know? `select meta_value ... where ... meta_value = 'Yes'` is only ever going to return `'Yes'`, so why bother with the query there at all?

Comment: @pala_: Not only the query, but also the data model is fundamentally broken :-)

Comment: @dnoeth i didn't get as far as to look at it - formatting the query was enough horror!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will avoid errors and might be what you actually want (although I can't see any relation between those field_ids and meta_values...)

```
SELECT sum(meta_value) 
  FROM wp_frm_item_metas 
  WHERE field_id=198 
    and EXISTS
     (select meta_value 
       from wp_frm_item_metas 
       where field_id=253 
         and meta_value="Complete") 
    and EXISTS
      (select meta_value 
        from wp_frm_item_metas 
        where field_id=278  
          and meta_value="Yes") 
    and EXISTS
      (select meta_value 
        from wp_frm_item_metas 
        where field_id=270 
          and meta_value=106)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DISTINCT` in your sub query, so this will not give error.